# How to customize / modify a Joomla template?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, joomla, lamp

I've downloaded and installed the LAMP stack, and the template meetGavern. I've got everything up and running, I ran the install procedure and now I can load up the meetGavern template site.

Now, I wish to get started morphing this template into my own personal website. I have no idea where to begin, this is my first time using Joomla.

I understand this is a broad question but oddly my searches are not giving me any direction, every resource I find seems to assume in-depth knowledge of Joomla.

Comment: Are you talking about modifying the design (styles, colors, fonts, etc), or adding content / rearranging content blocks / etc?

Comment: @JimL Just add/create/delete/edit content, pages, blocks etc.

Comment: I suggest you start here: https://docs.joomla.org/Tutorials:Beginners Just remember the templating part of a CMS is just the looks of the page, content and its placement is usually handled in other ways. You should read the menu, component and module parts of the tutorials.

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16524/how-to-modify-joomla-template-to-make-my-own-personal-site

Comment: @AlexVega thank you for answering my question there. i was not certain which site would give me the best answer